# How to Highlight a Part of the Text in the Screen on User Interaction

Tags: ios, swift, text

I have been trying to make a view which has (`textView` or `UILabel`) to show some paragraphs on the screen. I want it to be interactive with the user's touch. In addition, I want to divide the paragraph into sentences-like system. So, when the user touches different sentence, he get different options. For example, if the user touches `sentences1` the app asks the user if he wants to go to another `ViewController`, but when the user touches `sentence2` the app takes him to View `Controller2`.

I was an example that has the same thing that I wanna do.

```
ViewController
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNOKU.jpg
  View Controller1
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/00fCX.jpg

I hope someone could help me with this because I have been trying for days with no luck.

Comment: Can you please add code that you have tried?

Comment: I tried using UILabel, by creating many labels and each one has a GestureRecognizer for when the user clicks. But that is not practical, as if I wanted to create many paragraphs, I would need to create many labels and I practically can't align a lot of them the I want.